# Imageio or OpenCv saves black blank image after altering image array

Tags: python, opencv, encryption, 16-bit, python-imageio

Okay, I am trying to do sort of simple image encryption for my college project, all I need to do is open an image as a numpy array and **increment the pixel values by an integer key**, then save it as 16 bit image, then open that Image and. But whenever I increment the pixels the result turns into a deformed image of that only has shades of black, and when I try to get the original image by performing the reverse (decremented the pixels with the same integer key), it results in **a full black blank image**. The dimensions are correct but all the data seems to be lost(though when I print the matrices the values seem to be correct).

I have tried using Imageio with freeimage plugin, and open cv but nothing seems to work. I am also a noob so I don't know if I am missing something else

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
import os
import numpy as np


def encrypt(k):

    iload = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=Main,initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Please select a file:",filetypes = (("PNG files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    im= cv.imread(iload,cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    im = im.astype(np.uint16)   
    print("After Open File Type : ",im.dtype)
    print("Orinigal Image : ",im)   
    im = im.tolist()
    for l in range(len(im)):    
        for j in range(len(im[l])):
            for i in range(len(im[l][j])):
                im[l][j][i]+=k
    #im.putdata(npxls)
    im=np.array(im).astype(np.uint16)
    #imen.show()
    print("Encrypted Image : ",im)  
    #imageio.imwrite("encrypted.png",im,format='PNG-FI')
    cv.imwrite("encrypted.png",im)  
    img=cv.imread("encrypted.png",cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)    
    print("After Encrypting Saved File Type :",img.dtype)

def decrypt(k):

    iload = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=Main,initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Please select a file:",filetypes = (("PNG files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    im=cv.imread(iload, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    print("Original Image : ",im)
    print("After Decrypting Image Type: ",im.dtype)
    im = im.astype(np.uint16)   
    im = im.tolist()
    for l in range(len(im)):    
        for j in range(len(im[l])):
            for i in range(len(im[l][j])):
                im[l][j][i]-=k
    im=np.array(im).astype(np.uint16)
    #imen.show()
    print("Decrypted Image : ",im)  
    cv.imwrite("decrypted.png",im,[CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH ])    
    img=cv.imread("decrypted.png", cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    print("After Decrypting Saved Image type: ",img.dtype)
```

I just need the Image to get changed by adding a key to the pixel values in way that I can change it back with the reverse operation.

Comment: You don't need all those slow loops, just use `im += k`.

Comment: When reading, just use `cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` without the other flags.

Comment: without cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH it opens the file as 8bit

Comment: @SattwikRoy Given that `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` has the value of `-1`, you can bitwise-or it with anything you want, and the result will still be the same... `-1`.